# Office 365 Outlook add-in - can I show task pane in mail view mode?

Tags: outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook add-in for Outlook 365. 
When I'm in mail create window add-in is displayed in a nice vertical task pane on the right-hand side. Problem is that in email view mode the same add-in is displayed above mail context, in vertical window.

Can I use the same vertical task pane in email view mode?